# Should I describe automata before describing grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars

Let's say I want to describe some new grammar formalism, which doesn't coincide with known grammar sets. Should I always previously describe corresponding equivalent automata and why?

Comment: Not every grammar formalism has an equivalent automata formalism. It's nice if you can give several equivalent definitions for a class of languages, but that's it. There is certainly nothing in particular that you "should" do. It's all up to you.

Comment: Thank you, @YuvalFilmus. I always enjoy with your very good explained commentaries. Just wondering, why don't you form them as answers?

Comment: It's not my area so I want to give more appropriate answerers a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics, the only thing that you absolutely must do is prove every theorem. Everything else is optional. In this case, you are asking whether every grammar formalism must be accompanied with a corresponding machine model. There is no such requirement, simply because not all grammar formalisms have a corresponding machine model which is natural. It is just a "nice to have" feature. More generally, the definition of a new class of languages is more convincing if the class can be defined in many seemingly different ways.

Another thing which you don't have to do but is "nice to have" is discussing closure properties of your class of languages, discussing the complexity of the classical decision problems for your class, and relating your class to other classes of languages. This is how people have studied language classes in the past, and so you would be expected to do it.

Comment: However, ... the first thing that you absolutely must do is *motivate* your notions. Explain why I would be interested in your theory, so I will actually take the time to check the proofs.